# PHP - SOAP - WSDL: No Deserializer found to deserialize Error

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

This is the xml file format I have to use:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soapenv:Body>
<exec xmlns="CBWSCallEngine" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml">
<arguments>
<CbOrderProduct>
<Header>
<EndpointNm>123456789</EndpointNm>
<Certificaat>abcdef</Certificaat>
</Header>
<Detail>
<EAN>9789460941726</EAN>
<OrderReference>201406100527</OrderReference>
<ClientId></ClientId>
<ReadingMethods>D</ReadingMethods>
<RetailerId></RetailerId>
<License></License>
<RentalUnits></RentalUnits>
<RentalNumberOfUnits></RentalNumberOfUnits>
</Detail>
</CbOrderProduct>
</arguments>
</exec>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this is WSDL URL: https://tst.eboekhuis.nl/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL

everytime I try, I get below error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] No Deserializer found to deserialize a ':CbOrderProduct' using encoding style 'null'. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]

I tried simple SoapVar like below:

```
$xml .= '<CbOrderProduct>';
$xml .= '<Header>';
$xml .= '<EndpointNm>123456</EndpointNm>';
$xml .= '<Certificaat>abcdef</Certificaat>';
$xml .= '</Header>';
$xml .= '<Detail>';
$xml .= '<EAN>9789460941726</EAN>';
$xml .= '<OrderReference>201406100527</OrderReference>';
$xml .= '<ClientId></ClientId>';
$xml .= '<ReadingMethods>D</ReadingMethods>';
$xml .= '<RetailerId></RetailerId>';
$xml .= '<License></License>';
$xml .= '<RentalUnits></RentalUnits>';
$xml .= '<RentalNumberOfUnits></RentalNumberOfUnits>';
$xml .= '</Detail>';
$xml .= '</CbOrderProduct>';

$client = new SoapClient(
    null,
    array(
        'location' => 'https://tst.eboekhuis.nl:443/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine',
        'uri' => 'https://tst.eboekhuis.nl/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL',
        'trace' => 1,
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
    )
);
$params = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
$result = $client->exec($params);
```

Also I tried like below which I found on stackoverflow:

```
class CbOrderProduct
{
    var $Header;
    var $Detail;

    function __construct()
    {
                $this->Header = new stdClass();
                $this->Detail = new stdClass();
    }
    function setheader($endpoint,$Certificaat)
    {
        $this->Header->EndpointNm = $endpoint;
        $this->Header->Certificaat = $Certificaat;
    }   

    function setdetail($ean,$orderreference,$clienid,$readingmethods,$retailerid,$License,$RentalUnit,$RentalNumberOfUnits)
    {
        $this->Detail->EAN =$ean;
        $this->Detail->OrderReference = $orderreference;
        $this->Detail->ClientId = $clienid;
        $this->Detail->ReadingMethods = $readingmethods;
        $this->Detail->RetailerId = $retailerid;
        $this->Detail->License = $License;
        $this->Detail->RentalUnit = $RentalUnit;
        $this->Detail->RentalNumberOfUnits = $RentalNumberOfUnits;

    }   
}

class exec0Request {

    var $arguments;

    function __construct($arguments) 
    {
        $this->arguments = $arguments;
    }
}


$order = new CbOrderProduct();
$order->setheader('123456','abcdef');
$order->setdetail('9789460941726','201406100527','','CR','','','','');
$request = new exec0Request($order);
$client = new SoapClient("https://tst.eboekhuis.nl/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL");
$result = $client->exec(new SoapParam($request, "exec0Request"));
```

none of them work. I tried different type of xml files.

could anyone let me know what the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

```
Finally I have solved this issue.. :)
Below code will definitely work.

$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soapenv:Body>
<exec xmlns="CBWSCallEngine"
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml">
<arguments>
<CbOrderProduct xmlns="http://www.cbonline.nl/xsd">
<Header>
<EndpointNm>*********</EndpointNm>
<Certificaat>***********</Certificaat>
</Header>
<Detail>
<EAN>9789460941726</EAN>
<OrderReference>1988763767</OrderReference>
<ReadingMethods>D</ReadingMethods>
<RetailerId>12345</RetailerId>
</Detail>
</CbOrderProduct>
</arguments>
</exec>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$sUrl = 'https://tst.eboekhuis.nl/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL';

// set parameters

 $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$sUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    $sOutput = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($sOutput);
```