# PHP Soap request to eboekhuis

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I see a lot of questions about doing soap-requests to eboekhuis?
(https://tst.eboekhuis.nl:443/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL)

Will anybody share his/hers solution.
I'm stuck, I'm getting the error

> "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
>   Couldn't load from ..."

I turned the firewall out.
In php.ini:

```
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
```

and

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Looking forward to some answers.

Comment: You might want to add your code

Comment: I can, but I just replicate the code which are already on stackoverflow.

Comment: What code on SO are you talking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141498/how-do-i-send-this-xml-file-with-soap-and-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227371/php-soap-wsdl-no-deserializer-found-to-deserialize-error

Comment: There is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp) on SO that states it could be a problem with your php version not sending the user agent. Maybe this helps?

Comment: $order = new CbOrderProduct();
 $order->setheader('333','aaa');
 $order->setdetail('9789084999912','1988763767','K Koning','CR','12345');
 $request = new exec0Request($order);
    $opts = array('http'=>array('user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 $client = new SoapClient("https://tst.eboekhuis.nl:443/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL",
                             array('stream_context' => $context,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
 $result = $client->exec(new SoapParam($request, "exec0Request"));
    print_r($result);

Comment: Same result, see above code snippet

Comment: I think that it has something to do with the use of ssl and versioning.
    file_get_contents('https://tst.eboekhuis.nl:443/cbwebs/CBWSCallEngine?WSDL');
results in a 
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)